# In UE 5 I keep getting this error Unable to build while Live Coding is active

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

Since I upgraded to UE 5 I keep getting this error

> Error     Unable to build while Live Coding is active. Exit the editor
> and game, or press Ctrl+Alt+F11 if iterating on code in the editor or
> game

Any solution ?

Comment: @Crasher How to disable it in UE5 ?

Comment: just don't build with the Unreal editor open.

Comment: @Crasher live coding might be a form of hot reloading, but hot reload was in Unreal long before live coding was, and live coding is safe and you absolutely should use it. Epic bought out Live++ and integrated with Unreal specifically because their hot reload was broken.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe this is a solution, I choose `DebugGame Editor` profile

For error live coding not enabled for project dll you can try deleting the Binaries, DerivedDataCache, and Intermediate folders.

Answer (score 8):

Live coding is enabled on EU5 by default. This feature requires building from Unreal instead of from the IDE.

To initiate a build with live coding enabled, press `CTRL+ALT+F11`.

Source: https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/using-live-coding-to-recompile-unreal-engine-applications-at-runtime/

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well while trying to build from Visual Studio Code by selecting run build task from the Terminal menu while having UE 5 Editor running. The solution for me was as simple as following the error suggestion.

1. First, go to Edit > Editor Preferences > General > Source Code and make sure Visual Studio Code is selected.
2. While in Editor Preferences, go to Live Coding and make sure Enable Live Coding is enabled.
3. Make any code changes in VS Code and safe the file
4. Build from the UE Editor and not Visual Studio code by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F11 in UE Editor